# After replacing ASCII interpretations of accentuated words in Postgresql tables these changes are not shown in my Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I had names of cities in my DB that were shown like this 'C & oacute;rdoba' instead of Córdoba. This is, of course, because of the encoding. It is a very old table, maybe 20 years old, so probably before unicode UTF-8 was invented :))

So I changed all those escaping characters in the table with things like this:

```
SELECT nombre_localidad, 
replace(nombre_localidad,'&oacute;','o')
FROM localidades
```

as you can see, I removed the tilde so I left it as o instead of 'ó'
which works well when I see it on my PGAdministrator viewer for the tables, but when I returned to my Django Application and I pulled the list of cities from my select lists, they are still showing the original thing, C & oacute;rdoba instead of Cordoba.

Why is still Django picking the old data. Yes, I clicked on save data changes (F6) in my PgAdministrator

Comment: `very old table`, what PostgreSQL version and what encoding are you using?

Comment: version 6 something, encoding don't know but I solved the issue. My bad. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: No, you're kidding, are you seriously using PostgreSQL 6.something? The last 6.x version became OEL back in 2004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to clean you cache?

python manage.py clear_cache